# Airflow GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator error

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow

It has been 2 weeks that I'm facing a strange issue in my DAG. My use case is the following: A colleague uploads manually a file into a GCS bucket. This triggers a cloud function which in turn launches an Airflow DAG from the API.
The first task of the DAG is to transfer the file from a "landing zone" into a "save zone", then there rest of the DAG continues.

I move the file from bucket A to B with the **GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator**.
Everything was working until 2 or 3 weeks ago. The oldest DAG is 6 months old and even if we have changed some stuff it's on the other part of the DAG. So we've never touched that part and did not face any problems for a long time.

Now, most of the time the first task, the transfer, fails. The file is well moved, but for an unknown reason I have this error 2 or 3 times in a row if I retry, and the very next try, with the EXACT same file... it's working. I cannot find the factor that gives me this issue. I'm going crazy.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-10-15 09:34:50,599] {taskinstance.py:867} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2020-10-15 09:34:50,599] {taskinstance.py:868} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-10-15 09:34:50,620] {taskinstance.py:887} INFO - Executing <Task(GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator): transfer-landing-to-safe> on 2020-10-15T07:34:40+00:00
[2020-10-15 09:34:50,626] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 31555 to run task
[2020-10-15 09:34:50,775] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: geometrie-preprocessing.transfer-landing-to-safe 2020-10-15T07:34:40+00:00 [running]> blablabla.internal
[2020-10-15 09:34:50,860] {gcs_to_gcs.py:193} INFO - Executing copy of gs://blablabla-landing/geometrie/Track_Geometry-20201005_032915.csv to gs://blablabla-safe/geometrie/original/track_geometry_20201005_032915.csv
[2020-10-15 09:34:50,861] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-10-15 09:34:50,860] {gcp_api_base_hook.py:146} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2020-10-15 09:34:50,980] {taskinstance.py:1128} ERROR - 404 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/blablabla-landing/o/geometrie%2FTrack_Geometry-20201005_032915.csv/rewriteTo/b/blablabla-safe/o/geometrie%2Foriginal%2Ftrack_geometry_20201005_032915.csv: No such object: blablabla-landing/geometrie/Track_Geometry-20201005_032915.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gcs.py", line 178, in execute
    destination_object=self.destination_object)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gcs.py", line 196, in _copy_single_object
    self.destination_bucket, destination_object)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook.py", line 135, in rewrite
    source=source_object
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2098, in rewrite
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 423, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/blablabla-landing/o/geometrie%2FTrack_Geometry-20201005_032915.csv/rewriteTo/b/blablabla-safe/o/geometrie%2Foriginal%2Ftrack_geometry_20201005_032915.csv: No such object: blablabla-landing/geometrie/Track_Geometry-20201005_032915.csv
[2020-10-15 09:34:50,984] {taskinstance.py:1185} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.dag_id=geometrie-preprocessing, task_id=transfer-landing-to-safe, execution_date=20201015T073440, start_date=20201015T073450, end_date=20201015T073450
[2020-10-15 09:35:00,556] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-10-15 09:35:00,556] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

The operator part :

```
transfer_landing_to_safe = GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
        task_id=f"transfer-landing-to-safe{env_extension}",
        source_bucket=f"blablabla-landing{env_extension}",
        source_object="{{ dag_run.conf['file_name'] }}",
        destination_bucket=f"blablabla-safe{env_extension}",
        destination_object="geometrie/original/track_geometry_{{ dag_run.conf['file_name'][-19:] }}",
        move_object=True,
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id="gcp_conn"
    )
```

Comment: I believe that [this class is deprecated](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gcs.py). On the other hand, it is still in the [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gcs/index.html). But maybe you could try the `GCSToGCSOperator` class? ([Ref1](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_gcs.html), [Ref2](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_gcs/index.html))

Comment: @Ksign the way they import this operator with the providors name in it, tells me that the code you pointed me is for the v2 of AirFlow, so still in beta. I cannot but beta version in production. If you chose "stable" instead of "latest" you can spot the difference : https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gcs/index.html
In this repository, MASTER == v2.

Comment: The fact that it finally works is very strange but at the same time seems to indicate that at some point the file lands. Have you been able to check manually if the file is in the bucket when you get the first error? Or maybe with a `BashOperator` and a `gsutil` command?

Comment: Also, as you have created your own connection `gcp_conn`, I assume that your storage is in another project, right? Otherwise, have you tried removing this parameter to let the `google_cloud_default` connection and see if you get the same behavior?

Comment: Which version of airlfow are you using? Are you using contrib or backport?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not answering the question but in the new Airflow version, the `GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` has been deprecated in favor of `GCSToGCSOperator`:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_gcs import GCSToGCSOperator
```

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_gcs/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_gcs.GCSToGCSOperator

Hope this helps other users that need to upgrade Airflow version.